# Scrapy Parameters for parse method

Tags: python, parsing, methods, parameters, scrapy

i am coding a webcrawler with Python Scrapy which crawls through multiple pages of a tag directory and gain all tags and their articles.

So I got this parse method where the spider is running through every page.

```
def parse_word(self, response):

     # look for all tags on this site
     tagscount = response.xpath('someXpath').extract()

     # check if there is a nextPage
     nextPage = response.css('somecssSelector').extract()
     lastPage = response.css('somecssSelector').extract()

     # Open every tagsite and crawl it if all tags are gained
     if not nextPage or lastPage:

         for tag in tagscount:

             # call parse method for article crawling
             data = scrapy.Request(url=tag, callback=self.parse_subpage)
             yield data

     # If there is a nextPage with tags request with this method recursively
     else:

         # a little bit of formatting for linktype
         nextPageStr = str(nextPage)
         cutNextPageStr = nextPageStr.replace("[","")
         cutNextPageStr = cutNextPageStr.replace("]", "")
         cutNextPageStr = cutNextPageStr.replace("'", "")
         link = urljoin(response.url, cutNextPageStr)

         # Call this method again --> here i want to set a parameter tagscount or something like this
         data = scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_word)
         yield data
```

In the else section i want to give the parse_word method the gained tags, but the whole method takes only the tags of the last site.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i solved the problem. I implemented a class variable as a list and at every method call the tagscount variable.

Answer (score 0):

To propose an alternative solution, you could use a [spider middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) to perform the count, that would be stored in the request / response meta dictionary.

This is slightly cleaner in the sense that the responsibility for counting is separated from the responsibility of selecting elements from a page.

Comment: I do not know how to code this in the spider_middleware. Cause I implemented a IF and a For loop... Is there a other way?